# Slf4j adatper to java.util.logging.Logger

Tags: java, logging, slf4j, logback

I know that slf4j is interface that have a java.util.logging implementation. But what if I use slf4j and **must** pass an java.util.logging.Logger to some third part library? Is there wraper for slf4j logger that I can pass as java.util.logging.Logger?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html). I think jul-to-slf4j.jar is the droid you are looking for.